# Former Windows XP systems are slow after installing 14.04

Tags: graphics, performance

I just replaced windows XP on our work computer with Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit,  and it runs really slowly, only after logging into an account and the screen sometimes flashes.

It doesn't fill the whole screen, as if the screen has trouble displaying it.

When in the settings, when I hover over an item the rest of the items scramble as if there is a graphics problem.

I really like this software and want to make it work -- any ideas?

The OS is installed on the hard disc and completely replaced Windows XP.
It's fresh, no other file changes.

Comment: What graphics card do you have? Does `/usr/lib/nux/unity_support_test -p` show any failures?

Comment: If you haven't already done so, check the systems requirements of Ubuntu against your hardware: [How do I find out which version and derivative of Ubuntu is right for my hardware in terms of minimal system requirements?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/206407/how-do-i-find-out-which-version-and-derivative-of-ubuntu-is-right-for-my-hardwar) especially the RAM.

Comment: if you have low system specs,.. then you can try lubuntu `sudo apt-get install lubuntu-desktop` and choose lubuntu in log in screen